# The definition of "total curvature" for a scalar field

Tags: electrostatics, differential-geometry, voltage, curvature, harmonics

In *Modern Electrodynamics*, Zangwill remarks that the total curvature vanishes at every point where $\nabla^2 \varphi = 0$.

Now my question(s): how is "total curvature" defined for a scalar field (is it, perhaps, the "function" of $\hat{\bf{n}}$ for every unit vector $\hat{\bf{n}}$ which gives $(\hat{\bf{n}} \cdot \nabla)(\hat{\bf{n}} \cdot \nabla) \varphi$)? And how does the vanishing of the Laplacian at that point imply whatever the vanishing of whatever the definition of total curvature is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Zangwill is just being heuristic with the terminology here, and is using “curvature” to mean “second (partial) derivatives of the function”. He is interpreting each of the quantities $\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}, \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2} , \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2} $ as representing “curvatures in the $x,y,z$ directions”, and their sum as the “total curvature”. So, it seems to me he is making an essentially tautological point that the sum of the second partials vanishes at every point where the Laplacian (which by definition is the sum of the  second-order $x,y,z$ partials) vanishes.

Comment: I could try to talk about fundamental forms (of the graph of $\phi$) and so on, but I don’t think it’s going to make up for the heuristic terminology Zangwill adopts here.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for confirming!